# The last node in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am implementing a linked list in Java. Is it possible to create create and use an instance variable "lastNode" in the list collection class? Or I should always access the last node through following the links of the nodes starting form the first node?

Comment: Don't the java libraries have a linked list? It's usually called the 'tail'...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a `lastNode` (or `tail`) reference is completely viable and in fact very useful for certain applications.  Just remember, you need to update `lastNode` whenever another operation such as `Add()` or `Remove()` might affect it.

You may also wish to look up the concept of doubly-linked lists if you're not familiar with them already.  Depending on your applications, they can be very effective.